# Amazon S3 file upload fail using Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3

How to store a file in Amazon S3 using jsp page ????
I used FileInputstream but it doesn't work. Please give any suggestion about jsp code.

```
try
{
    String bucketName = "phr12345";
    File file=new File("a.txt");
    String key = "ads/" + file.getName();
    s3.putObject(bucketName, key, file);
    out.println("file uploaded !!!!!!");
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: At least `s3.(bucketName, key, file);` is not valid syntax.

Comment: Edited to Java, instead of JavaScript